# Generalised eigenvectors of a finite dimensional vector space

Tags: matrices, jordan-normal-form, root-systems

I'm currently reading Knapp's 'Lie Groups, Beyond an Introduction', and I can't seem to understand this point.

> Let $V$, be a finite dimensional $\mathbb{C}$-vector space, $\pi: \mathfrak{h} \rightarrow \text{End}_{\mathbb{C}}(V)$ a representation, and $\alpha \in \mathfrak{h}^*$. Define:$$V_\alpha = \{v \in V: (\pi(H) - \alpha(H)1)^n = 0 \text{ for all } H \in \mathfrak{h} \text{ and some }n  = n(H,v)\}$$
>   Since $V$ is finite-dimensional, $\pi(H) - \alpha(H)1$ has $0$ as its only generalised eigenvalue on $V_\alpha$ and is nilpotent on this space, as a consequence of the theory of Jordan normal form. Therefore $$n(H,v) = \text{dim}(V)$$

There are a few things which I'm not quite understanding here.

1. Why does $V$ being finite dimension mean there are no non-zero generalised eigenvalues?
2. Am I right in thinking by being nilpotent, he just particularly means that $$(\pi(H) - \alpha(H))^2 v = 0$$ since "$0$ is the only generalised eigenvalue".
3. Why is it that $n(H,v) = \text{dim}(V)$, how does this follow from the "theory of Jordan normal form"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First verify that $V_\alpha$ is a $\pi$-invariant subspace. It's saying that it can't have nonzero (generalized) eigenvalue **on** $V_\alpha$, not on the whole $V$.
2. Well, the exponent can be higher than $2$ to obtain $0$, otherwise yes.
3. In the definition of $V_\alpha$, the nilpotency level $n$ may depend on $H$ and $v$, which is true for the minimum of such $n$. However, here it states only existence, and the choice $n=\dim V_\alpha$ (or $n=\dim V$) works uniformly for all $H$ and $v$.

Comment: Why does the choice of dim V work uniformly for all H v?

Comment: If $T$ is a nilpotent transformation on an $n$ dimensional space, then $T^n=0$, as rank of $T^k$ must be strictly decreasing.